# How to integrate Appsflyer Uninstall measurement in an app with FCM installed?

Tags: android, appsflyer-android-sdk

I try to integrate AppsFlyer SDK with FCM already integrated in our app but stumbled upon the Uninstall Measurement part. The version of the app without AppsFlyer Uninstall Measurement is in Google Play Store and the version with it is not yet there. According to the [instructions](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/210289286#Android-Uninstall)  I followed (every step has been done) there should be no difference if we delete the app installed from Google Play or directly from computer (if I have interpreted words 'out of store' correctly). But still in our AppsFlyer account uninstalls are not shown after 24 hours of waiting.

1) The step 4 differs for users who have not integrated FCM yet and for users who have already integrated it in using different classes `FirebaseMessagingServiceListener` and `FirebaseMessagingService` respectively. Both classes are non-final. What bad could happen if we replace the second class with the first one?

2) I have noticed that the same article in other languages differs from the article in English. Which one is more actual and should be trusted?

Answer (score 0):

The appsflyer.`FirebaseMessagingServiceListener` extends Firebase's <>`FirebaseMessagingService` class, which is used in order to receive Firebase's Device Token. So both are actually the same.

So in case where you have a use case of sending Device Token to multiple third party libraries or to your backend, you should use `FirebaseMessagingService` and share the token to all the respective clients.

Or if you use `FirebaseMessagingServiceListener`, appsFlyer will do this step for itself. you don't need to manually send the token. So, its better to extend `FirebaseMessagingService` and use it in whatever way you want. Both are reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Like Prashant Jha wrote: In case where you have a use case of sending Device Token to multiple third party libraries or to your backend, you should use `FirebaseMessagingService` and share the token to all the respective clients.

To share the token with AppsFlyer you can use the `AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().updateServerUninstallToken(getApplicationContext(), token);` API